# How to resize images without cropping or losing quality?

Tags: html, image, sizing

I am trying to align images next to text, but am having issues with the image sizing.
I will be putting many rows of images next to text, so I need the images to all be the same size.

When I try to insert the image it will get distorted or cut off.

I am also hoping whatever changes made will look OK on mobile as well.

Any tips?

```
<div>
    <p style="float: left; padding-right: 50px;"><img src="https://blog.proven.com/wp-content/uploads/IND.jpg" height="200px" width="300px" border="1px"></p>
    <p><p align="right"><strong><font size="4">Proven Rating: <font color="#0077b3">★★★★★</font></font></strong></p>
Indeed is a widely used job board with over 200 million visitors a month, in 60 different countries. They post millions of job listings from other job boards, newspaper classifieds, personal ads, and more.</p>
</div>
```

Comment: [If lacking the code that exhibits the issue, then what is included is practically worthless.](http://idownvotedbecau.se/nomcve/)

Comment: So sorry! I have added the code. Thanks for letting me know.

Comment: Please extract your styles into an embedded `style` tag and eliminate extraneous markup, such as the `font` tag ([which is invalid in HTML5 anyway](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/font)).

Comment: Applying a fixed width/height prevents any mobile responsiveness, and you don't need to add `px` when using these image attributes.  `border` is not a supported attribute (Depreciated in HTML5) and `<font>` is also depreciated.

Comment: Why are you nesting `p` tags, and using HTML from the 90s

Comment: Because I am super new to this and have no idea what I am doing.

Comment: Be sure to follow recent guides that specify HTML5.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rather than inline size attributes, use CSS to set a maximum width on the image. This eliminates forced stretch.

```
img {
  max-width: 300px;
}
```

[Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/ea9pfxLc/)